# When I'm trying to enter marks in dictionary I couldnt do and the loop exits without it initiating

Tags: python

the one with three greater signs is the place where my code doesn't work

```
students = int(raw_input())
student_inf = {}
student_marks = []
for i in range(0,students):
    student_name = raw_input()
    student_inf[student_name] = {}
    for entry in student_marks:
    ---->>>>    student_inf[student_name][entry] = int(raw_input(entry))
print str(sum(student_inf[student_name].values())/3.0)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here you are trying to `loop an empty list` what is your desired output

Comment: for entry in student_marks: - The list student_marks is empty and this loop never executes.

Comment: student_marks is empty on execution

Comment: yeah can anyone provide a way to insert values into that entry

Comment: @A.r.Naresh: See below. Edited your code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over an empty list.
The correct way to do this would be:

```
students = int(raw_input())
student_inf = {}
student_marks = []
for i in range(0,students):
    student_name = raw_input()
    student_inf[student_name] = {}
    student_marks = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
    for entry in student_marks:
       student_inf[student_name][entry] = entry
    print str(sum(student_inf[student_name].values())/3.0)
```

With Input as:

`2 #Number of students
tom #Student Name
23 34 #Student marks separated by spaces
dick #Student Name
34 43 #Student marks separated by spaces`

And output:
`19.0
25.6666666667`

Comment: is there anyway of taking input of name and marks on same line @Vaulstein

Comment: `raw_input()` can be used to pass `n` number of user arguments. you can then use `split()`(<- split based on space) to store the values separately in different variables.
In your case, do `student = raw_input()` and then if you are sure if 1st argument was name, then `student_name = student[0]` rest store `student_marks = student[1:]`